# error AFTER DELETE Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I'm writing a new trigger, I'm sure it is ok, but i receive this error when I try to so the **SQL command**:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tax_delete
   AFTER DELETE ON cashflow FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      DELETE FROM tax_cashflow
      WHERE tax_cashflow.id_user = OLD.id_user
      AND tax_cashflow.id_orig = OLD.id_orig
      AND tax_cashflow.id_orig_user = OLD.id_orig_user;
    END;
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line  7

Can anyone help me to understand where is the error?
Thanks

Comment: you have no space between ANDtax  is a typo?

Comment: and when you have only one statement in the trigger omit the `BEGIN` and `END`. Or use a different delimiter.

Comment: no spaces between the words is only an error copyng the query. I don't know how other delimiter I can use

Comment: yes, you have reason,     I add delimiter $$
before running the CREATE and WRITE END$$ instead END;

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DELIMITER //    

create TRIGGER tax_delete
AFTER DELETE ON cashflow FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM tax_cashflow
WHERE tax_cashflow.id_user = OLD.id_user
AND tax_cashflow.id_orig = OLD.id_orig
AND tax_cashflow.id_orig_user = OLD.id_orig_user;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```